# How to add CSS configuration in reactjs Project?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I've written the webpackconfig but css doesn't seem to work properly and it is throwing and error. Following are my file's contains.

My webpack.config.js:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?/,
        include: SRC_DIR,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
        }
      }
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
      }
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!less-loader")
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css", {
      allChunks: true
    })
  ]
};
```

and in my Index.js I've added as :

```
import '../assets/css/style.css';
```

Package.json :

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error saying? Also, may you please upload you `package.json`

Comment: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| .title{
|   margin-bottom: 30px;
| }
 @ ./src/app/index.js 16:0-34

Comment: Try this `loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]` and `ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css-loader!sass-loader")`

Comment: {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css-loader!sass-loader")
      }'

Comment: Like this??????

Comment: Yes like that. Let me know if it helps

Comment: No. It's not solved.

Comment: What error are you getting now? Please upload your package.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160483/discussion-between-riya-kapuria-and-brandnew).

Comment: Can you please check the discussion??

Answer (score 1):

As per our [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160483/discussion-between-riya-kapuria-and-brandnew), this is what your `webpack.config.js` file is as below:

```
var path = require("path"); 

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"); 
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src"); 

var config = { 
  entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js", 
  output: { 
    path: DIST_DIR + "/app", 
    filename: "bundle.js", 
    publicPath: "/app/" 
  }, 
  module: { 
    loaders: [ 
      { 
        test: /\.js?/, 
        include: SRC_DIR, 
        loader: "babel-loader", 
        query: { 
          presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"] 
        }
      } 
      { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"] 
      } 
      { 
        test: /\.less$/, 
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css-loader!sass-loader") 
      } 
    ] 
  }, 
  plugins: [ 
    new ExtractTextPlugin("src/components/assets/css/style.css", { 
      allChunks: true 
    }) 
  ] 
}; 

module.exports = config;
```

There are two issues with this config.

1. The are no commas separating the `loaders` objects.
2. You are using `ExtractTextPlugin` but have not imported/required it anywhere in the config.

Issue #1 is quite obvious how to solve; simply add the commas after each definition of a loader object.

Issue #2 as well, you need to install and reference `ExtractTextPlugin` in you webpack config file.

You can do so by running the following command in your terminal:

```
npm install --save-dev extract-text-webpack-plugin
```

This will install the plugin to your `node_modules` and also list it in your `package.json file under the`devDependencies` object.

And then in your `webpack.config.js` where you are requiring modules, also require the plugin like so:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
```

After making these changes, you config file should look something like this:

```
var path = require("path"); 
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"); 
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src"); 

var config = { 
  entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js", 
  output: { 
    path: DIST_DIR + "/app", 
    filename: "bundle.js", 
    publicPath: "/app/" 
  }, 
  module: { 
    loaders: [ 
      { 
        test: /\.js?/, 
        include: SRC_DIR, 
        loader: "babel-loader", 
        query: { 
          presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"] 
        }
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"] 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.less$/, 
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css-loader!sass-loader") 
      } 
    ] 
  }, 
  plugins: [ 
    new ExtractTextPlugin("src/components/assets/css/style.css", { 
      allChunks: true 
    }) 
  ] 
}; 

module.exports = config;
```